# How do I accept a ReSharper namespace import suggestion using my keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When coding, I often type a declaration with a type name from a namespace not yet imported with a `using` statement. ReShaper then pops up a little tooltip suggesting a namespace for which to automatically add a `using`. However, I always have to leave off typing and use my mouse to accept this. How can I do this using only the keyboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> whilst the caret is on the type you are trying to use. But it does depend on the schema you are tying to use or if the short cut has been customized.

Here are the short cut keys for Visual Studio and IDEA:
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html

Here is also a nice pdf print out for the Visual Studio schema (6.0)
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper60DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf

Comment: Funny that the shortcut is actually specified in the import pop-up: http://i56.tinypic.com/s4t7yg.png I wonder if it's in a blind spot or something

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @Bronumski answers your direct question but you dont *need* to type the class name, instead for a type that requires an import statement you should partially type the class name then use Shift-Alt-Space: consider this example:

[image]

Suppose you want to import `StreamReader` - you type the first few characters, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then press Enter and the class name *and* the import will be added for you.

Comment: Agreed and use this most of the time. The only time I really used the Alt + Enter approach was when I pasted code in but now with 6 we can use the new "Import types for pasted code" which indecently uses the Alt + Enter short cut but does it all in one go :)

Comment: @Bronumski "which indecently uses the " <-- i hope you meant indirectly! :)

Comment: Actually meant to say "incidentally" but I let chrome spell check for me without looking at the result :$

Answer (score 4):

Out of the box, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

To set it yourself, or see what you currently have it set to, go to
Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, enter "ReSharper_QuickFix" in the textfield "Show commands containing", and select a shortcut from there.

Comment: +1 I like the way you did the Alt + Enter, very nice and clear.

Comment: @Bronumski see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70356/key-stroke-combination-markdown for how to do that

Comment: @wal Can't change my answer now, that would be plagiarism :)

Comment: In ReSharper 8 the quick fix command has been renamed to ReSharper_AltEnter